# Put a UIViewController inside a UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have no idea how to do this.  I tried this:

```
class CardsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var cardController = CardViewController()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.height = cardController.card.height
        contentView.addSubview(cardController.view)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

but I am having no luck.

Comment: Why add an entire UIViewController into a UITableViewCell? Why not just add a UIView?

Comment: ...well I am a beginner that's never designed UIs.  That sounds a lot easier. thank you

Comment: Great, glad to be of help. Just be sure to come back and modify your question a bit more if you have any problems setting things up with a UIView.